# Get Data from Editable H2 to Input

Tags: javascript, html

I have one editable h2 tag and one editable p ta and two inputs and I am trying to get the data from editable h2 and p tags and assign them to the inputs. How can I make that? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="yin">
                    <nav id="nav">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><h3 class="heading-title">Publish</h3>

                <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 18px; margin-top: -15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></li>
                    <li><h3 class="heading-title sub">cover</h3></li>
                        <input type="button" name="upload" value="Upload" >
                    <li><h3 class="heading-title sub">blurb</h3></li>
                        <textarea name="blurb" id="blurb" placeholder="170 character limit. Keep it short. Keep it sweet." maxlength="170"></textarea>
                    <li><h3 class="heading-title sub">genre</h3></li>
                         <select id="genre" name="genre">
                            <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
                            <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
                            <option value="Humor">Humor</option>
                            <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
                            <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
                         </select>
                        <a href="#" class="subscribe">+</a>
                        <a href="#" id="sub-publish" class="publish" onclick="document.getElementById('theSbmit').click()" >Publish</a>

                        <!-- damn contenteditable can't be passed on --><form id="form" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="form-title"></input>
    <textarea name="story" id="form-message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="theSubmit" value="submit"></input></form>

                        <!-- save -->

                    <li><h3 class="heading-title">save</h3>
                    <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 18px; margin-top: -15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></li>
                    <li><h3 class="heading-title sub">notes</h3></li>
                        <textarea id="notes" placeholder="Reminders and/notes to yourself?"></textarea>
                        <a href="#" class="publish">Save</a>
                 </ul>
            </nav>


    <!-- Main -->
            <section id="main" class="wrapper" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
                <div class="container">

                    <header class="major special">
                        <h2 contenteditable="true" id="titled">Your Title</h2>
                        <p>Chapter 1</p>
                    </header>
                    <article >
                    <p id="storyd" contenteditable="true">Vi accumsan feugiat adipiscing nisl amet adipiscing accumsan blandit accumsan sapien blandit ac amet faucibus aliquet placerat commodo. Interdum ante aliquet commodo accumsan vis phasellus adipiscing. Ornare a in lacinia. Vestibulum accumsan ac metus massa tempor. Accumsan in lacinia ornare massa amet. Ac interdum ac non praesent. Cubilia lacinia interdum massa faucibus blandit nullam. Accumsan phasellus nunc integer. Accumsan euismod nunc adipiscing lacinia erat ut sit. Arcu amet. Id massa aliquet arcu accumsan lorem amet accumsan.</p>

                    </article>

                </div>
            </section>

        <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(function(e) {
    var title = $('#titled').text(),
    var story = $('#storyd').text();

    $form.find('input[name="title"]').val(title);
    $form.find('input[name="story"]').val(story);
return false;


});

        </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

The inputs are on nav and the editable h2 and p on section. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be working apart from there is one small mistake. In your JS the line `var title = $('#titled').text(),` ends with a comma (`,`) rather than a semi-colon (`;`).

You also may wish to use `e.preventDefault();` in the first line of your form submit function to prevent the page redirecting to the form post destination. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

As noted by Zak, you have placed a comma instead of a semi-colon at the end of `var title = $('#titled').text()`

Also, `$form.find('input[name="story"]').val(story);` should be `$form.find('textarea[name="story"]').val(story);`